# Onedrive not syncing many folders. Why?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

[image]

Just look at those pictures. Onedrive says your files are synced.

And yet so many folers like htdocs, hyk Documents are not synced.

Status is still waiting to sync.

What is going on.

Checking on onedrive online shows that those files are indeed not synced.

Update: I tried Gantendo approach and got this
[image]

So when folders are already on onedrive I have an option of not seeing that. However, my case is the other way around. Folders are in my hard drive but onedrive never sync it.

Update: I tried to move files out of onedrive and in again. It seems that lots of folders have weird permission like no one own the folder.

I add my own username and give all permission. I can get files in and out onedrive easily.

However, onedrive still takes too long for

> looking for changes.

[image]

Now it's been looking for changes for hours.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/choose-which-onedrive-folders-to-sync-to-your-computer-98b8b011-8b94-419b-aa95-a14ff2415e85

Comment: What happens if you close the OneDrive client, and then reopen it?

Comment: One Drive is not magic. It tries to sync all of My Documents plus anything else you specify. Make certain your documents are safe. Copy them to an external drive to make a copy. Unlink your PC from One Drive. Restart.  Set up One Drive and let it sync.

Comment: OneDrive does not synchronize every file extension. That probably explains why htdocs isn't synchronizing.  Likewise, Documents cannot be selected from that particular menu, and you have to select Documents from Settings->Manage Backup.  OneDrive also has a file size limit.

Comment: All those files are used to be in onedrive. I moved them around and try to get them back.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can help if you set the file synchronization status of the respective folders to "online only", and then a few minutes later back to "keep everything synced on this device".

Comment: I will try. Okay